# Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'ХХХ'.

Tags: android

Не могу никак собрать проект. Все время вылезает вот такая ошибка. Что это и как с этим бороться?

> Errors occurred during the build.
> Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'ХХХ'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в потоках. Вы пытаетесь обратиться к null. Как отдебажить точно я пока не знаю, сам только с java знакомлюсь.